# How to gain OAuth user token without web login?

Tags: oauth, facebook4j

Is there any way I can get a OAuth user token with the user details (username, password etc?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework) defines 4 flows by which a client application can get an access token issued by an authorization server. Among them, [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) can be used to get an access token by presenting username and password.

The following is an example of a token request using Resource Owner Password Credentials flow (an excerpt from RFC 6749):

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
```

However, probably, Facebook's authorization server does not support Resource Owner Password Credentials flow.